# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class android.content.res.ColorStateList declares multiple JSON fields named mChangingConfigurations

Tags: api, android-studio, serialization, gson, retrofit

I am trying to fetch movies from TMDb wevsite by simple GET Request but it shows the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class android.content.res.ColorStateList declares multiple JSON fields named mChangingConfigurations` . 
I am not able to understand the exact problem.
I have read about this error and apparently it has something to do with Serialization (or) basically my some error is occuring while converting into Gson.

Here is my method for calling

```
    public void loadMovies(TMDbApi api, int page){
    Call<MoviePage> call = api.getPopular(API_KEY,LANGUAGE,page);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<MoviePage>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MoviePage> call, Response<MoviePage> response) {
            movies = response.body().getResults();
            allMovies.addAll(movies);
            Log.d("Movies","Movies Size "+ allMovies.size());
            adapter.updateData(movies);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MoviePage> call, Throwable t){
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my TMDb api interface

```
public interface TMDbApi {

@GET("movie/now_playing")
Call<MoviePage>getPopular(
    @Query("api_key") String apiKey,
    @Query("language") String language,
    @Query("page") int page
);

@GET("movie/{id}")
Call<MovieBlock>getMovie(
    @Path("id")int id,
    @Query("api_key") String apiKey,
    @Query("language") String language
);

@GET("search/movie")
Call<MoviePage>getSearch(
        @Query("api_key") String apiKey,
        @Query("language") String language,
        @Query("query") String query,
        @Query("page") int page
);
```

}

Here is my Response class

```
public class MoviePage {
@SerializedName("page")
@Expose
private Integer mpage;
@SerializedName("total_results")
@Expose
private Integer totalResults;
@SerializedName("total_pages")
@Expose
private Integer totalPages;
@SerializedName("results")
@Expose
private List<MovieBlock> mresults = new ArrayList<>();

public Integer getPage() {
    return mpage;
}

public void setPage(Integer page) {
    this.mpage = page;
}

public Integer getTotalResults() {
    return totalResults;
}

public void setTotalResults(Integer totalResults) {
    this.totalResults = totalResults;
}

public Integer getTotalPages() {
    return totalPages;
}

public void setTotalPages(Integer totalPages) {
    this.totalPages = totalPages;
}

public List<MovieBlock> getResults() {
    return mresults;
}

public void setResults(List<MovieBlock> results) {
    this.mresults = results;
}
```

}

Here is my Movie class

```
public class MovieBlock {
@SerializedName("popularity")
@Expose
private Double mpopularity;
@SerializedName("vote_count")
@Expose
private Integer voteCount;
@SerializedName("video")
@Expose
private Boolean mvideo;
@SerializedName("poster_path")
@Expose
private String posterPath;
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer mid;
@SerializedName("adult")
@Expose
private Boolean madult;
@SerializedName("backdrop_path")
@Expose
private String backdropPath;
@SerializedName("original_language")
@Expose
private String originalLanguage;
@SerializedName("original_title")
@Expose
private String originalTitle;
@SerializedName("genre_ids")
@Expose
private List<Integer> genreIds = null;
@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
private String mtitle;
@SerializedName("vote_average")
@Expose
private Double voteAverage;
@SerializedName("overview")
@Expose
private String moverview;
@SerializedName("release_date")
@Expose
private String releaseDate;

Button watchListButton;
Button watchedButton;

private boolean watchList = false;
private boolean watched = false;
private String IMAGE_URL = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/";

public boolean getWatchList(){
    return watchList;
}
public boolean getWatched(){
    return watched;
}
public void setWatchList( boolean watchList ){
    this.watchList = watchList;
}
public void setWatched( boolean watched ){
    this.watched = watched;
}

public Double getPopularity() {
    return mpopularity;
}

public void setPopularity(Double popularity) {
    this.mpopularity = popularity;
}

public Integer getVoteCount() {
    return voteCount;
}

public void setVoteCount(Integer voteCount) {
    this.voteCount = voteCount;
}

public Boolean getVideo() {
    return mvideo;
}

public void setVideo(Boolean video) {
    this.mvideo = video;
}

public String getPosterPath() {
    return posterPath;
}

public void setPosterPath(String posterPath) {
    this.posterPath = posterPath;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return mid;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.mid = id;
}

public Boolean getAdult() {
    return madult;
}

public void setAdult(Boolean adult) {
    this.madult = adult;
}

public String getBackdropPath() {
    return backdropPath;
}

public void setBackdropPath(String backdropPath) {
    this.backdropPath = backdropPath;
}

public String getOriginalLanguage() {
    return originalLanguage;
}

public void setOriginalLanguage(String originalLanguage) {
    this.originalLanguage = originalLanguage;
}

public String getOriginalTitle() {
    return originalTitle;
}

public void setOriginalTitle(String originalTitle) {
    this.originalTitle = originalTitle;
}

public List<Integer> getGenreIds() {
    return genreIds;
}

public void setGenreIds(List<Integer> genreIds) {
    this.genreIds = genreIds;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return mtitle;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.mtitle = title;
}

public Double getVoteAverage() {
    return voteAverage;
}

public void setVoteAverage(Double voteAverage) {
    this.voteAverage = voteAverage;
}

public String getOverview() {
    return moverview;
}

public void setOverview(String overview) {
    this.moverview = overview;
}

public String getReleaseDate() {
    return releaseDate;
}

public void setReleaseDate(String releaseDate) {
    this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
}

public String getIMAGE_URL() {
    return IMAGE_URL;
}

public void setIMAGE_URL(String IMAGE_URL) {
    this.IMAGE_URL = IMAGE_URL;
}
void onButtonClick(){

}
```

}

I would also like to add a note. App works fine in API 29 but crashes for every other API below 29.

My compile and target SDK version is 29.

Comment: Why do you have `Button`s in `MovieBlock`? I would guess that those are the issue.

Comment: I have removed the buttons. The app works now. Thanks a lot. May I ask why it caused a problem..

Comment: I'm not sure where the error was happening, and I'm not very familiar with those libraries, but I think at some point, GSON was attempting to process the `Button` class for (de)serialization, which means it started going through all of its internal members, until it hit a `ColorStateList` field where it finally choked. You can't serialize `View`s of any kind, so those `Button`s need to be excluded. Beyond that, I would imagine that the API level discrepancy is due to the increasing lockdown on reflection, and on 29, it wouldn't even get to where it would try to process the problematic field.

Comment: Oh. Thanks again I understand much better now..